# make switching across windows smoother in Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, brightness, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell-extension

so here's the problem: when you have a dark IDE and a you have to switch back and forth with a light website page, you experience these **abrupt brightness changes** which hurt your pupils (they do not have enogh time to adjust).

Is it just me or someone else too experience this problem? Should I see a doctor?

Generally, this is the case when you have to switch between windows with significantly different brightness levels.

Keeping your windows mostly light (or dark) somehow works but isn't always possible.

So i was wondering if there are some extensions/tricks etc. to make Alt-Tab transitions smoother to get eyes a bit of time (0.2 s should be okay) to adjust.

How can we solve it? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 using Gnome 3